# Parallelism and intersection at ideal points under projective transformation

Tags: geometry, projective-geometry

This is rather a basic question in projective geometry but I have come across a line in section 2.7.2 (recovery of affine properties from images) from Multiple View Geometry (Hartley & Zisserman)
[image]

What is the significance of this statement? Does it suggest anything about the lines still being parallel? If 2 lines after projective transformation still intersect at a point at infinity on $l_{\infty}$, it seems to suggest that they are still parallel.

In an earlier section of 2.4.5 the authors gave an example to show a point at infinity is mapped to a finite point under projective transformation. Therefore as I understand parallelism is not preserved. I would like some help understanding the example given in the screenshot.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
https://medium.com/@unifyai/part-ii-projective-transformations-in-2d-2e99ac9c7e9f
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You missed the word “imaged,” which abbreviates “image of.” A general projective transformation will certainly move the line at infinity to some other line.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit with the imaged $l_{\infty}$? I am a beginner to this topic

Comment: It means where the line gets mapped by the projective transformation. In principle, it could be any line (possibly the same one) in projective space.

Comment: the text seems to refer to 2 planes from the projective transformation. is it talking about the correspondence of parallel lines in the 2 planes? I have added a diagram to the post, are these red and blue planes the original and images planes?

Comment: I can't try to interpret pages of a textbook by mental telepathy. It seems his projective transformation is mapping the red plane to the blue and fixing the green. So it maps the line of intersection of the red and green planes to the line of intersection of the blue and green planes.